# Android:Application Level Tag to make app work in landscape mode only

Tags: android, android-manifest

Is there any application level tag to make app work in landscape mode only ? I know we have activity level tag i.e   android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" but this is redundent code if all the activities are to be in landscape mode ?

Comment: I am sure you checked the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html Does not seem to be the case.

Comment: i couldn't find such a tag in this documentation . . so it means we have declare this for all the activities of our application